# Find the density

Tags: probability, trigonometry

> Suppose that radius $R$ of one sphere is a continuous random variable
>   with density $$f_R(r)=6r(1-r) I_{[0,1]}(r)$$ Find $f_V(v)$ and
>   $f_S(s)$ the densities of volume and surface area

I did the course probability a long time ago and now I'm remembering some things.I know that volume $V=g_1(r)=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ and $S=g_2(r)=4\pi r^2$. So for find that densities is just
$$f_V(v)=f_R(g_1^{-1}(v))\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial v}g_1^{-1}(v)\right|$$
$$f_S(s)=f_R(g_2^{-1}(s))\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial s}g_2^{-1}(s)\right|$$
or is there something more behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks mostly right, except you probably meant $g_2^{-1}(s)$ where it says $g_1^{-1}(s)$, you didn't introduce $y$, and since the person specifying $f_R$ was finicky enough to include $I_{[0,1]}(r)$ there, they probably want you to include the characteristic function in $f_V$ and $f_S$, too.

By the way, you can make those absolute value bars look much nicer by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: I corrected the errors. What you mean by "include the characteristic function"?

Comment: The problem statement includes the characteristic function $I_{[0,1]}(r)$ of the interval $[0,1]$ on which $f_R$ is defined, so apparently $f_R$ is being considered on all of $\mathbb R$; the characteristic function ensures that it's $0$ outside the domain of interest. To maintain consistency with that style, you need to include a corresponding factor in your densities; otherwise the finicky person who wrote the problem would probably say that they're "wrong" because they're not zero where they should be.

Comment: Well, I thought for characteristic function you meant $\varphi$, here we call just "indicator" $I$